# is it mandatory to include "originator" to json while sending an adaptive card to outlook via Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, outlook, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I am working on an adaptive card which has `Action.OpenUrl` actions in it and I am trying to send the same via Power Automate to Outlook.

The problem is when I send it to myself, the adaptive card is displayed in the email body but when I trigger the same email to my team members, the adaptive card is missing in the email body.

Has anyone faced any similar issue with adaptive cards? has anyone worked on sending adaptive cards to outlook? if yes, is it mandatory to register at `https://outlook.office.com/connectors/oam/publish` for actionable messages to be sent to Outlook and to add the 'originator' to the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documentation at: [Additional properties on the AdaptiveCard type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card#outlook-specific-adaptive-card-properties-and-features)

> For actionable email, `originator` **MUST** be set to the provider ID generated by the [Actionable Email Developer Dashboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/email-dev-dashboard).

**Additional Reference**: [Adaptive Cards in Outlook – Ultimate Guide](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerautomate-en/adaptive-cards-in-outlook-ultimate-guide/)

> Once you open Actionable Message debugger for a message containing Actionable Message it will show you all the issues with it. For Like in the below example, where I sent Actionable Message **without originator ID**, so not from a registered provider:

[image]